# Dedicated server for killing floor in objective mode / story mode

Tags: killing-floor, hosting

I run two Killing Floor dedicated servers on Linux (one Normal, one Hard) for playing with friends. We would like to run an Objective mode (story mode?) server as well.

What configuration changes / command line parameters do I need to add to run an objective mode server?

I have googled my heart out for this but I only find cryptic hints, such as [this](http://forums.gamingdeluxe.net/showthread.php/11245-Killing-Floor-new-storymode) and [this](http://steamcommunity.com/app/1250/discussions/0/864972399824180197/)

Note: I don't use the web panel and would rather not enable it for security reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this one out.

I modified my start script from this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -xe

cd ~killingfloor/killingfloor/System
./ucc-bin server \
    KF-bioticslab.rom?game=KFmod.KFGameType?VACSecured=true?MaxPlayers=6 \
    -nohomedir \
    -ini=killingfloor.ini
```

to this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -xe

cd ~killingfloor/killingfloor/System
./ucc-bin server \
    KFO-Steamland.rom?game=KFO.MOD?VACSecured=true?MaxPlayers=6 \
    -nohomedir \
    -ini=killingfloor.ini
```

i.e. change `game=KFmod.KFGameType` to `game=KFO.MOD` and the map from `KF-bioticslab.rom` to `KFO-Steamland.rom` (or some other objective map)